# AppStorage variables are not updated the first time

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

As said in the title, 2 of the 3 `@AppStorage` variables aren't updated the first time. So, when the view is dismissed, I have to re-open it and then at the second dismiss they're all updated. To be precise, only `storedCityName` is updated the first time.

Here's the view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject private var searchManager: SearchManager
    @AppStorage("storedUserLatitude") private var storedUserLatitude: Double?
    @AppStorage("storedUserLongitude") private var storedUserLongitude: Double?
    @AppStorage("storedCityName") private var storedCityName: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $searchManager.search)

            ForEach(searchManager.searchResults, id: \.self) { result in
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text(result.title)
                        Text(result.subtitle)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture { update(result.title) }
            }
        }
    }

    private func update(_ city: String) {
        searchManager.searchLocation(city)
        storedUserLatitude = searchManager.userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
        storedUserLongitude = searchManager.userLocation?.coordinate.longitude
        storedCityName = city
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

And, here's the manager:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import Combine

class SearchManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    private let completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    @Published var search = ""
    @Published var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()
    @Published var userLocation: CLLocation?
    private var publisher: AnyCancellable?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        completer.delegate = self
        completer.resultTypes = .address

        publisher = $search
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { string in
                self.completer.queryFragment = string
            })
    }

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results
    }

    func searchLocation(_ city: String) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(city) { placemarks, error in
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
            self.userLocation = placemark.location
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why it works at the second try but not at the first one.

I also tried to delay the `dismiss` with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { dismiss() }` to see if the `@AppStorage` variables needed time to update but it doesn't change anything.

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Alexnnd, note, I deleted my answer because it is not correct. A bad answer should not be here.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Alright, no problem. But are you sure about `@AppStorage` and optional because I have no error from Xcode so I suppose that it's possible.

Comment: no, I'm not sure. The dosc at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults do not mention Optionals, and I saw an older post saying it is not possible. But my tests seem to work with optionals. Maybe things have changed.

Comment: I think you're right, because I remember that the last year I couldn't use optional for `@AppStorage`. Things changed hopefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you call your reverse geocoder with `searchManager.searchLocation(city`), which uses an async function to do the reverse geocoding. While you pass a block to that to set the values in your search manager, the code in `SearchView` isn't waiting for that information.

On the second try, your SearchManager environment object has had time to update with the geocoding from the first attempt.

You should consider updating `searchLocation` to make sure that it only runs the subsequent code in `update` once the geocoding has happened. One way would be to allow it to receive a block:

```
private func update(_ city: String) {
  searchManager.searchLocation(city) {
    storedUserLatitude = searchManager.userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
    storedUserLongitude = searchManager.userLocation?.coordinate.longitude
    storedCityName = city
    dismiss()
  }
}

// in SearchManager
func searchLocation(_ city: String, onComplete: () -> Void) {
  let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

  geocoder.geocodeAddressString(city) { placemarks, error in
    guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
    self.userLocation = placemark.location
    onComplete()
  }
}
```

There are neater ways, and you'd need to handle the error path properly, but hopefully this gives you the right idea.

Comment: You're absolutely right. If I put all the stuff from my `update()` function into `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2)` it works perfectly fine. So, there's a delay with `searchLocation()`.

Comment: I get this error with the code of the second func: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'onComplete'.

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to mark the `onComplete` as `@escaping` in the `searchLocation` function definition. That compilation error should give you a fix-it option.

Comment: I had to add `@escaping` here `searchLocation(_ city: String, onComplete: @escaping () -> Void)` and now it works perfectly fine. Thank you so much!